# How can I recreate this carving onto a new body?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, workflow, 3d-printing

I have a scan I'm trying to recreate, its a wheel rim part and Im a beginner in blender, I can't recreate the carving that I circled in on the picture, I tried using cylinder with array so I can keep up the symmetry but it messed up the new body mesh real bad, and in the 3D printer slicer it generated a lot of problems, it was not printable. I'm kinda out of ideas, I have no idea how could I recreate that engraving, so I could appreciate any tip on how to recreate, or maybe a solution. I also tried to sculpt it out but it was inaccurate to the original body, and well it just looked ugly.
[image]

[image]

The pictures contain the scanned mesh